# Cannot get ESP32 to go into bootloader mode. Is there something wrong with my circuit?

Tags: microcontroller, schematics, esp32

I've designed a board to monitor a water tank and control a relay. I didn't opt to install a USB programmer to save on costs as it will be single install and OTA updates.  Right now, I'm trying to flash it using an FT232 adapter and it keeps failing to connect.  The  schematic is below.

The reset has a button but the boot mode is two header pins.

Does anything jump out as being wired incorrectly that would cause this not to boot?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: looks good to me, but I usually use a 6 wire programming cable and let the loading software handle the reset and boot mode for me automatically.

Comment: 12V relays are a thing that could reduce your power needs

Comment: Hmm I wonder if it’s an issue with my ftdi. The only other thing I can see in the data sheet is it says to pull-up GPIO2 however other sources say the internal pull-up is enough. What 6 pins would you use to auto reset ? I’ve been looking at the esp programmer but the connector is huge

Comment: I use 5v relays as the voltage could drop below 12v on the supply and I need the relay to still function

Comment: most 12V relays are operable down to 8v

Comment: It's an ESP-Prog module ,  it's based around FT2232 and a couple of transistors, the schematic is on the Espressif site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I made the mistake of not reading the datasheet correctly. On other ESP32 devices they use GPIO0 for bootloader but on the C3 Mini it is GPIO9

Redesign has been done and have changed to a 12V relay, too.

Answer (score 0):

Are there RTS and DTR pins on the FT232? I think they need to be connected to the EN and GPIO9 pins on the C3 in order to start it in bootloader mode:

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/esp32c3/advanced-topics/boot-mode-selection.html

Comment: I have buttons on board i can use instead of the adapter auto doing that as I haven't broken out EN to the headers.